# woocommerce Auto-login on checkout page just with billing_email

Tags: woocommerce, hook-woocommerce

I'm trying to create a snippet so that when the customer types their email in the billing_email field, WooCommerce performs an auto-login if they are already a registered customer. The following code can perform automatic login by email, but I'm not able to get the page to recognize the login. The login is recognized when I refresh the page or go to another page on the website.

```
// Modify the auto_login_guest_user function
add_action('woocommerce_checkout_update_order_review', 'auto_login_guest_user', 10, 1);
function auto_login_guest_user($post_data) {
    if (is_user_logged_in()) {
        return;
    }

    parse_str($post_data, $checkout_data);
    $email = $checkout_data['billing_email'];

    if (email_exists($email)) {
        $user = get_user_by('email', $email);
        if ($user && !user_can($user, 'administrator') && in_array('customer', $user->roles)) {
            // Log the user in.
            wp_set_current_user($user->ID);
            wp_set_auth_cookie($user->ID);
            do_action('wp_login', $user->user_login, $user);

            // Trigger the login event
            $message = '<div class="woocommerce-message">logged_in</div>';
            $woocommerce_messages = array($message);
            add_filter('woocommerce_add_message', function() use ($woocommerce_messages) {
                return $woocommerce_messages;
            });
        }
    }
}
```

The JS (Here, I added a redirect to the cart page, which is also not working.)

```
jQuery(document).ready(function($) {
    // Listen for the checkout update event
    $(document.body).on('updated_checkout', function(e, data) {
        if (data.fragments && data.fragments['.woocommerce-message']) {
            var message = data.fragments['.woocommerce-message'];
            if (message.indexOf('logged_in') > -1) {
                // Redirect to the cart page
                redirectToCartPage();
            }
        }
    });

    // Trigger checkout update when billing email is changed
    $('form.checkout').on('change', 'input#billing_email', function() {
        $(document.body).trigger('update_checkout');
    });

    // Function to redirect to the cart page
    function redirectToCartPage() {
        var cartUrl = '/carrinho-de-cotacao/'; // Change this to the correct cart page URL if needed
        window.location.href = cartUrl;
    }
});
```

Comment: Hmm, you want to log in a customer without typing a password? It's possible but bad idea.

Comment: We work with wholesale products, and generally, customers are always requesting quotes. With automatic login, it's easier to identify customers and provide personalized service. If it were retail, I would agree with you 100%.

Comment: Another point is that we don't store payment information on the site. In this way, it's quite unlikely that someone would pay for an order on behalf of another customer.

Comment: Cool, you are logged in inside the ajax call, the easiest way is to refresh the page with location.reload(); after the ajax call is returned.

Comment: `$(document.body).on('updated_checkout', function(e, data) {
        if (data.fragments && data.fragments['.woocommerce-message']) {
            var message = data.fragments['.woocommerce-message'];
            if (message.indexOf('logged_in') > -1) {
                // Refresh the page
                location.reload();
            }
        }
    });`

Comment: I tried this way before as well, but without success. The code above maybe isn't   part of the problem, I think another issue is the theme. I need to delve deeper into the behavior of the "WOODMART" theme.

Answer (score 0):

Working like a charm ..

```
function enqueue_auto_login_script() {
    if ( is_checkout() && !is_user_logged_in()) {
wp_enqueue_script('auto-login-guest', get_stylesheet_directory_uri() . '/js/auto-login-guest.js', array('jquery'), '3.8', true, 0);
    }
}
add_action('wp_enqueue_scripts', 'enqueue_auto_login_script');


// // Modify the auto_login_guest_user function
add_action('woocommerce_checkout_update_order_review', 'auto_login_guest_user', 10, 1);
function auto_login_guest_user($post_data) {
    parse_str($post_data, $checkout_data);
    $email = $checkout_data['billing_email'];
    
    if (empty($email)) {
        return;
    }
    if (is_user_logged_in()) {
        $current_user = wp_get_current_user();
        if (!empty($email) && $email !== $current_user->user_email) {
            wp_logout();
        } else {
            return;
        }
    }

    if (email_exists($email)) {
        $user = get_user_by('email', $email);
        if ($user && (user_can($user, 'administrator') || user_can($user, 'shop_manager'))) {
            // Do not auto-login administrators or shop managers
            $message = wc_add_notice('Este e-mail não pode ser feito auto login', 'error');
            $woocommerce_messages = array($message);
            add_filter('woocommerce_add_message', function() use ($woocommerce_messages) {
                return $woocommerce_messages;
            });
        } elseif ($user && in_array('customer', $user->roles)) {
            // Log the user in.
            wp_set_current_user($user->ID);
            wp_set_auth_cookie($user->ID);
            do_action('wp_login', $user->user_login, $user);

            // Trigger the login event
            $message = wc_add_notice('Login Realizado com Sucesso', 'success');
            $woocommerce_messages = array($message);
            add_filter('woocommerce_add_message', function() use ($woocommerce_messages) {
                return $woocommerce_messages;
            });
        }
    } else {
        // Create new customer account
        $username = strstr($email, '@', true);
        $password = wp_generate_password();
        $new_user_id = wp_create_user($username, $password, $email);

        if (!is_wp_error($new_user_id)) {
            wp_update_user(array('ID' => $new_user_id, 'role' => 'customer'));
            // Log the new user in.
            wp_set_current_user($new_user_id);
            wp_set_auth_cookie($new_user_id);
            do_action('wp_login', $username, get_userdata($new_user_id));

            // Trigger the new customer event
            $message = wc_add_notice('Novo Cadastro', 'success');
            $woocommerce_messages = array($message);
            add_filter('woocommerce_add_message', function() use ($woocommerce_messages) {
                return $woocommerce_messages;
            });
        } else {
            // Error creating new customer account
            $message = wc_add_notice('Erro ao criar nova conta de cliente', 'error');
            $woocommerce_messages = array($message);
            add_filter('woocommerce_add_message', function() use ($woocommerce_messages) {
                return $woocommerce_messages;
            });
        }
    }
}
```

JS file Child-theme (js/auto-login-guest.js):

```
jQuery(document).ready(function($) {
    $('form.checkout').on('change input touchend', 'input#billing_email', function() {
        setTimeout(function() {
            location.reload();
        }, 2000);
    });
});
```